# Magento2 sales_shipment_grid problem

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I just truncated `sales_shipment_grid`, but want to know that how can regenerate it.
Means that have all data on `sales_shipment` yet but there is nothing on `sales_shipment_grid` and this table is empty. Actually, I want to regenerate it.

PS: I tried setup:upgrade, di:compile, static-content:deploy, reindex, flush cache too.

Comment: If you haven't a backup you need to create a query to insert records calculated from sales_shipment

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please let me know the query?

Comment: I just only suggest you to create an insert with select from sales_hipment with the fields you have to fill